# JavaScript Text not submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am working on my first web application and I am trying to use javascript to submit a form by clicking on text. When I click on the text nothing happens. It should just open to a simple webpage for now. I know how to process forms with html, but when I try and use javascript nothing happens. I am using unix and i have already configured my server and chmod 755 the cgi file. I not it is not a server error as I have executed cgi files on it before. I am following this tutorial:
http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/textsubmit.shtml

Here is my test html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>EDVT Report Generator</title>
    <style>
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

            function getsupport ( selectedtype )
            {
              document.supportform.supporttype.value = selectedtype ;
              document.supportform.submit() ;
            }

        </script>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id = "title">Test</h1>
    <form name="supportform" method="post" action="/cgi-bin/hello.py">
        <input type="hidden" name="supporttype" />
        <a href="javascript:getsupport('Paid')" onclick = "getsupport('Paid')">Paid Support</a> or
        <a href="javascript:getsupport('Free')" onclick = "getsupport('Free')">Free Support</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the cgi file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgitb, cgi
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

I am at a complete loss with what is wrong as I do not have much experience with javascript. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you have your script inside the `<style>` tag, therefore, no script. Looking at error console in any browser would've shown you that getsupport is not defined

Comment: Don't put `getsupport('Paid')` in both `href` and `onclick`. That will run it twice.

Comment: WOW thanks that worked! But in my actual code which is must lengthier, that is not the issue. My script is outisde the style tag but it still does not worl

Comment: If any of you want to help with the actual problem i posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330981/javascript-not-submitting-hidden-form-when-clicking-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot nest a `<script>`element inside `<style>`, the only allowed content is CSS. See e.g. [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style).

Move `<script>` to either `<head>` or `<body>`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>EDVT Report Generator</title>
    <style>
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

            function getsupport ( selectedtype )
            {
              document.supportform.supporttype.value = selectedtype ;
              document.supportform.submit() ;
            }

     </script>
    <h1 id = "title">Test</h1>
    <form name="supportform" method="post" action="/cgi-bin/hello.py">
        <input type="hidden" name="supporttype" />
        <a href="javascript:getsupport('Paid')" onclick = "getsupport('Paid')">Paid Support</a> or
        <a href="javascript:getsupport('Free')" onclick = "getsupport('Free')">Free Support</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```